# How can I get the one to many relationship's many entity in nested response?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class Movie

```
public class Movie
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Producer ProducerName { get; set; }
    }
```

and a class Producer

```
public class Producer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

They have a one to many relationship from Producer to Movie i.e a producer can have multiple movies and a movie has only one producer.

I am getting the Movie details with below query.

```
var result = _context.Movies
                    .Include(m => m.ProducerName)
                    .ToList();
```

I get below Json:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Venom",
        "producerName": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Amy Pascal",
            "movies": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Venom"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I want all the movies associated with the producer in the same query?

Like

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Venom",
            "producerName": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Amy Pascal",
                "movies": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Venom"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 56,
                        "name": "something"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 81,
                        "name": "else"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: Using the query in one of the answer, I only receive a single movie of the producer(the current one) and not all of them.
I see the database and find that even though it is a one to many relationship from producer to movie, there are multiple rows inserted for the same producer(with different primary keys). My question differs a little here. I am seeding the database using a json. The IDs(PK) are database generated.

JSON used to seed the database:

```
[   
  {
    "Name": "Venom",
    "ProducerName": 
          {
               "Name": "Steven Spielberg"
          }   
  },
  {
    "Name": "Kung Fu League",
    "ProducerName":
          {
               "Name": "Steven Spielberg"
          }  
  }
]
```

How can I constraint the EF Core to not create duplicate rows for the same producer and not a generate a different key for same producer as then I might receive all the movies of a single producer successfully?

Comment: Are you wanting the full list of movies for the producer under each individual movie? You'd need to do another call to movies from the producer Id for that. You might be able to add it as a sub Include or Select but I've not checked.

Comment: `var result = _context.Producers.Include(p => p.Movies).ToList();`

Comment: No. I want to get the list of movies, include the producer of the movie and get "all the movies the producer has produced" in the same call. We get that in a many-to-many relationship. But this is a one-to-many relationship. A bit confusing to get the nested call.

Comment: You got me interested, trying something up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain includes. Start first from `Movies` then [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) `Producers` and finally use [`ThenInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels) to include the movies of the producers.

**Update:**

As pointed out by @Gert Arnold when projecting (not returning your entities), [Includes are ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes) by EF Core so, if going with my option of projecting into something else you can remove the `Includes`.

So:

```
// use .Include and .ThenInclude when returning your entities
var returningEntities = context.Movies
                                 .Include(p => p.ProducerName)
                                 .ThenInclude(m => m.Movies).ToList();

// No need for Include when use projection
var returningAnonymousObject = context.Movies
    .Select(a => new
    {
        id = a.Id,
        name = a.Name,
        producer = new
        {
            id = a.ProducerName.Id,
            name = a.ProducerName.Name,
            movies = a.ProducerName.Movies.Select(m => new
            {
                id = m.Id,
                name = m.Name
            })
        }
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: `Include` and `ThenInclude` don't have any effect here. You can remove them.

Comment: How so? I just tested this and for sure it works, resulting in exactly what OP wants. Might not be the most efficient query, but that's not the question here, at least IMO.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work, but projections don't need includes and even remove them from the query. See [ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes).

Comment: Ah forgot about that, you're right. I've seen the warning it produces last week, funny. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Include query just returns the current movie of the producer. I see the database and find that even though it is a one to many relationship from producer to movie, there are multiple rows inserted for the same producer(with different primary keys). My question differs a little here. I am seeding the database using a json. The IDs(PK) are database generated. How can I constraint the EF Core to not create duplicate rows for the same producer and not a generate a different key for same producer?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the only way I can think of is somehow "sanitizing" your json file before inserting it into the DB. OR, you could insert the JSON data as-it-is into a, let's say, import table then manipulate that table to exclude duplicates and then insert the correct values into the "real" table. You could create a procedure that does the work, and just call it during your EF seed.

Comment: But I'd say that's another question.. so you might get more help if you open another one. I could give it a try as well.

Comment: Somehow, I am not allowed to ask another question. However, I did modify my json(not convenient, but works for now) and now I am able to fetch the required result. Marking your answer as correct as it did help me.